# NSURL URLWithString not working properly in iOS7

Tags: uiwebview, ios7, nsurlrequest

I am experiencing very strange behaviour with `NSURL URLWithString`.

I am trying to load a webview with the following code:

```
/* DOES NOT WORK */ NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://njs1.example.com:3000/assets/0/2147484153/642/645/77b9430e-bde8-4284-af7d-300b3474eeb9.pdf"];
/* WORKS! */ NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

It **does not work** when I try to load the following URL:

```
http://njs1.example.com:3000/assets/0/2147484153/642/645/77b9430e-bde8-4284-af7d-300b3474eeb9.pdf
```

**NOTE: The link above is generated on request by the server with customer headers.**

It **works** when I load the following URL:

```
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf
```

The code above works fine in iOS 5 and iOS 6 but not in iOS 7. Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: The following error is relevant: `Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0xd798730 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://njs1.imaginationplus.com:3000/assets/0/2147484153/642/645/77b9430e-bde8-4284-af7d-300b3474eeb9.pdf, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://njs1.imaginationplus.com:3000/assets/0/2147484153/642/645/77b9430e-bde8-4284-af7d-300b3474eeb9.pdf, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}`

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the URL that is not working is being generated by the server on request? That url is not a direct link to the file. It is being generated with custom headers on the server using Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response headers are severely malformed, according to Chrome's developer tools

[image: Network inspector]

Comment: Hmm. Any idea's on what it should look like? What could be causing the issue? I don't really have much control over this part of the code.

Comment: Could be one of a million things, but it's an issue on the server side  for sure. iOS 7's webkit powered webview appears to be rejecting the header where iOS 6 may have tolerated it.

Comment: I got it!
Had to set `"Content-type" -> "application/pdf"`

Thanks :)